# Instant crashing after replacing calls to clock() with MPI_Wtime()

Tags: c++, mpi, exit-code

I have an MPI program that I'm developing on a local computer, but need to run on a remote machine. I used `clock()` to measure time, but after discovering that it doesn't work well enough on the remote machine (due to a completely different architecture), I replaced a few calls to `clock()` with `MPI_Wtime()`, which yielded the required results. The program still runs on both the local and remote machines.

However, I just went and replaced all the other calls to `clock()` with `MPI_Wtime()`, and now launching the program on the local machine immediately causes the processes to stop with exit code -1073741819. Even if I put a `cout` in the very first line of `main()`, there's no output, so I'm fairly sure it's not a programming fault on my part, but I have no idea what's wrong.

How can changes in the source code cause a program to fail before the changed code (or any code, for that matter) is executed?

Comment: Have you called MPI_Init before your first cal to MPI_Wtime?

Comment: You haven't called MPI_Wtime before MPI_Init have you ?

Comment: Try making a copy of the program that is as simple as possible but still displaying the crash.  Then post your code here.

Comment: I tried moving the call to `MPI_Init()` to the very first line of `main()`, to no effect. On a side note, if that was the source of the error, then I would think that the `cout` in the first line would still have been displayed.

Comment: Are you calling `MPI_Wtime()` from the constructor of a static object? These run before `main()`.

Comment: @Mike: add that as an answer, you hit the jackpot. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you calling `MPI_Wtime()` from the constructor of a static object? These run before `main()`.

Answer (score 0):

Was that cout flushed by an 'endl' or 'flush' manipulator?  If not, the program may have crashed afterwards but you'd never know because the buffered output would be lost.